# Timeout error and connection getting lost

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the code in localhost server it works properly but when we run the same code in our live server (Godaddy linux shared server) it gives sql connection failed error. 
The database is quite big and in our local server the query takes approximately 2 minutes to return data, so in shared godaddy server it must take more time.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","doreme_eshop");

// $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "doreme_eshop");
// if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
//     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
// }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $style=$_REQUEST['style_no'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"CALL style_report('".$style."')") or die("Query Failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));

//var_dump($result->fetch_assoc());

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>total_set</th>
<th>style_no</th>
<th>size_id</th>
<th>size_description</th>
<th>Company_name</th>
<th>generate_no</th>
<th>order_Date</th>
<th>product_id</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['total_set'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['style_no'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['size_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['size_description'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Company_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['generate_no'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['order_Date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['product_id'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}



?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="style_no" >
<option value="">STYLE NO</option>
<?php
 $style_result = mysqli_query($conn,"CALL get_all_style_no()") or die("Query Failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));

$row1 = mysqli_num_rows($style_result);
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($style_result)){
echo "<option value='". $row1['style_no'] ."'>" .$row1['style_no'] ."</option>" ;
}
?>
</select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at `mysqli::options` in the php documentation. You can manually set the timeout for the connection before you connect to the database.

Comment: The mysql connection settings for your shared host are probably different from your local host. You need to make sure you are using the correct connection settings

Comment: i see a few possible security issues within this code `mysqli_query($conn,"CALL style_report('".$style."')")` -> SQL injection.. `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` -> Cross site scripting..  i have to say `CALL` like that most likely can't be attacked with SQL injection but better to be safe then sorry right.. Unless the SP uses dynamic SQL and use that input which i assume here then SQL injection is very very possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set time out on connection, secondly u can set the config file to be separated and require_once.

Try check if the DB has mysqli library,... just open connection only then close and check error

Comment: a fine comment (maybe) ... but certainly not an answer.  Wait till you have enough rep to comment on OP.